# Ruby: Run loop if variable set

Tags: ruby

I'm executing a command with in ruby using open3, and Im setting a timeout using the safe_timeout gem (because of known issues with timeout reported [here](https://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/4681))

The code I have is very simple:

```
SafeTimeout.timeout(t) do
  stdout, stdeerr, status = Open3.capture3(cmd)
  @output = stdout
  @result = status.exitstatus
  @pid = status.pid
  @timeout = t
end
```

The caveat here is that I only want to run this within the timeout block if `t` is defined.

Obviously I can use an if statement but then I'd have duplicate stuff and it doesn't feel very "ruby-like" to me.

Is there a nice way to do something like:

```
if t
  timeout.do
    command
  end
else
  command_without_timeout
end
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [Proc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Proc.html) - the reified version of a Ruby code block. Put your command in the proc, and then either pass the proc to the `timeout` method (using the `&` operator to pass it as a block instead of a normal parameter) or else just `call` it directly.  Example:

```
block = proc do
  # this is the code I want to run
  # with or without the timeout 
  stdout, stdeerr, status = Open3.capture3(cmd)
  @output = stdout
  @result = status.exitstatus
  @pid = status.pid
  @timeout = t
end

if t then
  SafeTimeout.timeout(t, &block)
else
  block.call
end
```

Comment: Awesome! This is what I ended up with. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Quick question actually. I also want to get the duration of the block to determine how long it took to execute. When running block.call I can just do the following:

          `startTime = Time.now
          block.call
          @duration = Time.now - startTime`

However doesn't seem clear to me how to do this with `&block` - is there a way?

Comment: Why can't you do it with the timeout version, too?   `startTime = Time.now; if t then SafeTimeout.timeout(t,&block) else block.call end; @duration = Time.now - startTime`

Comment: Ignore me, it was a stupid question anyway. I know how long it took because I set a timeout for it to end. D'oh